# Updating GitHub issues from GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I was trying to make a GitHub action using some simple scripts (which I already use locally) that I would like to run inside a docker container.

A new issue should trigger the event to update the said issue with its content based on some processing. An example of this might be:

Say I have a list of labels defined in my script and it checks the issue's title and adds a label to the issue.

I'm still reading the GitHub Action's documentation so I may be not completely informed but the issue I seem to have is that in my local machine these scripts use `gh` cli for doing such tasks (eg. adding labels). So I was wondering if I need to have the `gh` installed in that docker container or is there a better way to update the issue? I'm very much willing to make these scripts from scratch again using the GitHub's event payloads and stuff as long as I don't have to write in TypeScript.

I've looked around the documentation and couldn't find anything that talked about updating issues. Also couldn't find a similar question being asked here; it may be that I've missed something so if that is the case direct me to relevant material and I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An option** could be (as you said) to install GH in that docker container, and then run GH commands.

*Example using a container:*

```
jobs:
 build:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  container: 
    image: docker://myrepoandimagewithghinstalled
  steps:
    - name: Github CLI Authentication
       run: gh auth login --hostname <your hostname>
    - name: Github CLI commands execution samples
       run: |
         gh command1
         gh command2
         gh command3
```

**Another option** could be to install GH directly on the OS (for exemple ubuntu-latest), authenticate, and then use the "run" option to execute GH command.

*Example installing GH on the OS:*

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
       - name: Install Github CLI
          run: |
            sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key C99B11DEB97541F0
            sudo apt-add-repository https://cli.github.com/packages
            sudo apt update
            sudo apt install gh
       - name: Github CLI Authentication
          run: gh auth login --hostname <your hostname>
       - name: Github CLI commands execution samples
         run: |
           gh command1
           gh command2
           gh command3
```

**Finally**, you could also create a script consuming the [Github API service to update an ISSUE](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#update-an-issue) and execute the script using the run option.

*Example to execute a Python script in your workflow:*

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: checkout repo content
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 # checkout the repository content to github runner.
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8 #install the python needed
      - name: execute py script # run the run.py to get the latest data
        run: |
          python run.py
        env:
          key: ${{ secrets.key }} # if run.py requires passwords..etc, set it as secrets
      - name: export index
        .... # use crosponding script or actions to help export.
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using GitHub API. I made a Go program inside a docker containers and passed the Github Token as an environment variable for authentication.